# curl of differential volume element?

Tags: calculus, differential

I have an equation involving $\nabla \times \left( q \vec v \right) $ , where I call "q" the "charge" and "v" the "velocity".  I now want to change this to a current density $ q \vec v \to \vec J dV$.  So I then have $ \nabla \times \left( \vec J dV \right)$.
The question is, does $ \nabla \times \left( \vec J dV \right) = \left( \nabla \times \vec J \right) dV$ , where $ dV = dxdydz $ is a differential of volume. If not, how does one evaluate $ \iiint \nabla \times \left( \vec J dV \right) $?  If I can pull out the $ dV $from the curl how do I show that this is correct mathematically?

Comment: Do you know anything about measures and/or differential forms?

Comment: Whether one treats $dV$ as differential form or a measure, it's not obvious how $\nabla \times (\vec J dV)$ should be defined. The only way I can think of to define it is as $(\nabla \times \vec J) dV$.

Comment: I thought of that, but this $ \left( \nabla \times \vec J \right) dV $ would only be valid if $ dV $ is treated as a constant.  I don't think it is right to treat it as a constant.   And I've heard of measures and I've heard of differential forms, and read a little on differential forms, but I have never used them, so I don't know them.

Comment: Since the Lebesgue measure, e.g. $dV$, is translation invariant, I would certainly consider the spatial derivative of it be zero.